# How to delete a corrupted file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

I make a backup disk with bad sectors on Ubuntu.
Some files are not copied and do not give a full backup.
I want to remove them, but get the error:

```
rm: can not remove [file]: Input / output error
```

I can not stop the server. How can I remove the bad file is to continue backing up without stopping?

Comment: It could be file system specific. If Ext3 or Ext4, consider using *carefully* [debugfs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/debugfs). Be aware that you could lose all your data (so take several hours to read documentation). Perhaps work on a byte copy of the file system image.

Comment: Which filesystem? Did you already try `fsck`? But I think this question should be migrated over to Unix & Linux.

Comment: I can not experiment because not sure that this will not affect server performance. I am very critical server performance.
File system Ext4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use tar with an exclude pattern to skip all problematic files.

```
tar -X file_with_list_of_files_to_skip cfz backup.tgz folder_to_backup
```

You can populate the file_with_list_of_files_to_skip with the cleaned up output of a filesystem checking utility.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, but rsync and exclude-from - to no avail.

Comment: Did you build a list of all corrupt files first?

Comment: Rsync gives high LA. Using tar, everything turned out better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can run cmd-prompt as an administrator, then run `chkdsk /X /f C:` (C: can be changed to the file starting thingy). And it will auto recover :)

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what exactly the "file starting thingy" is?

Comment: the drive letter corresponding to your USB drive

Comment: if its your computer, then C: